# Identificar el campo en una consula inner join mysql

Tags: mysql

El siguiente código ejecuta una consulta INNER JOIN

```
select * from reservation 
INNER JOIN pacient ON pacient.id_history LIKE '%2%' 
GROUP BY pacient_id 
ORDER BY pacient_id DESC limit 0,12
```

Resulta que al consultar el id hay un ligero choque, habrá alguna forma de solucionar eso

Comment: Se incluyen varias etiquetas que aparentemente no tiene relación con la pregunta ¿hay alguna razón relevante para incluirlas?

Comment: Lo primero es que usar `select *` no es una buena idea, porque es muy posible que estés seleccionando columnas que **nunca** vas a usar. Por otra parte, puedes usar alias de tablas y seleccionar las columnas de cada tabla que desees. Ejemplo: `select p.id paciente_id, p.nombre, r.id from reservation r
INNER JOIN pacient p ON p.id_history LIKE '%2%' 
GROUP BY pacient_id 
ORDER BY pacient_id DESC limit 0,12` verás que en el select se ha usado un alias para la columna `id` de la tabla `paciente`. La palabra `AS`  es opcional. Otra opción sería llamar a la columna `paciente_id` directamente.

Answer (score 2):

Cuando existen choques como dices, lo mejor es cualificar las tablas y asignar alias. Se recomienda cualificar siempre los campos y no utilizar el comodín *, por varios motivos, las consultas serán más eficientes, pues sólo llamaremos a los campos que necesitemos y el motor no tendrá que buscar que campos tiene la tabla. También  las consultas serán más legibles, pues viendo la consulta sabremos que campos nos va a devolver.

Vayamos al lio.

Esta consulta

```
select * from reservation 
INNER JOIN pacient ON pacient.id_history LIKE '%2%' 
GROUP BY pacient_id 
ORDER BY pacient_id DESC limit 0,12
```

podría quedar de la siguiente manera

```
SELECT 
    reservation.id reservation_id, 
    reservation.otro_campo, 

    pacient.id pacient_id, 
    pacient.otro_campo_pacient
FROM reservation 
INNER JOIN pacient ON pacient.id_history LIKE '%2%' 
GROUP BY pacient_id 
ORDER BY pacient_id DESC limit 0,12
```

Igualmente hacer un LIKE en el INNER JOIN no me parece lo más apropiado. Lo normal es que se utilice una igualdad algo como esto:

```
SELECT 
    reservation.id reservation_id, 
    reservation.otro_campo, 

    pacient.id pacient_id, 
    pacient.otro_campo_pacient

FROM reservation 
INNER JOIN pacient ON reservation.pacient_id = pacient.id
GROUP BY pacient_id 
ORDER BY pacient_id DESC limit 0,12
```